# inhertance by prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, datetime

I now in javascript.
I have a qustion about inhertants by prototype.
How can takes a year with out use **proto**
I have function Vehicle

```
 function Vehicle(name,color,year){
            this.name=name;
            this.color=color;
            this.year=year;
        };
```

and function  liveTime

```
Vehicle.prototype.liveTime=function(){
            return new Date().getFullYear() -this.year;
            
        };
```

we can inhertans by prototybe (BUT prototype is a property of a Function object. It is the prototype of objects constructed by that function.)

here we can inhertance by it

```
 function Vehicle(name,color,year){
            this.name=name;
            this.color=color;
            this.year=year;
        };


        Vehicle.prototype.liveTime=function(){
            return new Date().getFullYear() -this.year;
            
        };

        var car= new Vehicle('y','red',2000);
        console.log(car.liveTime());
```

The Qustion is why can inhertans by prototype without use  **proto**

Comment: e.g. [Introducing JavaScript objects :: Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: I read it but I don't understand

Comment: The OP also could give a try to ... Dmitry Soshnikov's [JavaScript. The Core: 2nd Edition - Prototype](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core-2nd-edition/#prototype) ... by playing around with the various mentioned techniques of accessing (and altering) an object's prototype.

Comment: "*…why can inhertans by prototype…*" because that's how the language is specified to work. Constructors (functions) have a public *prototype* property, instances created by a constructor inherit via their private `[[Prototype]]` property that references the constructor's *prototype*. An object's properties are resolved first on the object itself, then on the private `[[Prototype]]` chain.